# Linux LFTP connecting and mirroring folder over FTPS without certificate verification on bitbucket pipelines

Tags: linux, ftp, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, lftp

I've been trying to deploy my dist folder via bitbucket pipelines + lftp for quite a while now. I've tried various variations of the linux commands and gone through a couple dozen articles on the issue yet I still can't get the thing to work.

So far my pipeline commands look like this:

```
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install lftp
  - lftp set ssl:verify-certificate no
  - lftp $FTP_HOST
  - user $FTP_USER
  - $FTP_PASSWORD
  - ls
  - quit
```

But for set I'm getting `'lftp: set: Name or service not known'` -- when I delete the step it gets to user and I'm getting `bash: user: command not found` if I add lftp in front of it I'm getting `lftp: user: Name or service not known`

I think in total I've tried over 30+ times to get these right with no luck.

Comment: @shellter that's not pseudo-code, that's exactly how the inside of the bitbucket pipelines-yml file looks like and it's exactly what you'd write. Each line being a step it takes during the continuous deployment.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying that. So it seems that the problem is inside "bitbucket pipelines". Hopefully other readers have solved this problem. Good luck!

Comment: FYI: it is unsecure to disable ssl verification as pointed out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44095714/1973022) Anyway I didn't get lftp to run without verification so far.

Comment: Update: Now lftp runs with verification, there just had to be added some certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no complete solution as I don't know bitbucket, but I see clearly one mistake:

You cannot change lftp settings in subsequent command calls. That's what you are actually doing:

1. You invoke `lftp` with wrong command line arguments `set ssl:verify-certificate no`.
2. `lftp` quits with error message `set: Name or service not known`. Even if you would have gotten the setting inside lftp in step 1 it would be cleared now because of the quit.
3. You invoke `lftp` with (probably) right command line argument '$FTP_HOST'.
4. Now 'lftp' quits, probably because it gets no commands on stdin.
5. You mean to go all the other commands (user, password, ls, quit) to go to lftp as stdin, but according to the logs they are treated as further shell commands.

So please look how to send stdin to a program with bitbucket. (For information on stdin: it is refered to as "input" in following tutorial which explains how shell works: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_01_03 )